# Getting tag after tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the first tag after another tag with beautifulsoup.

Let's suppose i have this:

```
<span class="number">5</span>
<span class="b">xxx</span><span class "number">10</span>
```

I could get the number on the second .number with a regex and it would be pretty solid. But we all know regex isn't supposed to parse html, so i'm doing this with beautifulsoup. Currently i'm doing this with

```
soup('span', {'class': 'number'})[1].string
```

but, if at another span.number is inserted before the one i want, it will break the code, since the one i need will become [2].

Is there any way to use beautifulsoup to get the first span.number AFTER span.b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [next_sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the next tag after `<span class="b">`:

```
import bs4 as bs


content = '''<span class="number">5</span>
<span class="b">xxx</span><span class "number">10</span>'''

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
print(soup('span', {'class': 'b'})[0].next_sibling)
# <span class="">10</span>

print(soup('span', {'class': 'b'})[0].next_sibling.string)
# 10
```

If you are using BeautifulSoup version 3, the equivalent attribute is called [nextSibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#nextSibling%20and%20previousSibling).